# Суммировать расход по каждому имени

Tags: excel

Имеется таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

она начинается с ячейки А1 ( я не знаю как сюда таблицу вставить).

Необходимо посчитать сколько потратил Ваня, сколько Петя

Расход Ваня =

Расход Петя =

скорее всего надо использовать ВПР?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае применять `ВПР` нет нужды. Вам поможет функция `СЧЁТЕСЛИ`. Используется она в вашем случае следующим образом:

```
=СУММЕСЛИ(C2:C4;"Ваня";B2:B4)
```

Первый аргумент функции - это диапазон, использующийся для проверки критериев. Мы помещаем туда область, ограничивающую столбец с указанными именами.

Второй аргумент функции - это сам критерий выбора (в нашем случае требуемое имя).

Третий аргумент функции - это диапазон с числами, которые потом будут суммироваться, если в соответствующей ячейке первого диапазона находится значение, удовлетворяющее критерию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант1.**

```
=СУММЕСЛИ(C:C;"Ваня";B:B)
```

Или в столбец *D* вписать имена, в столбце *E* получить результат:

```
 =СУММЕСЛИ(C:C;D2;B:B)
```

Функуция прекрасно понимает, где последняя строка с данными, поэтому диапазон столбца можно не ограничивать.

**Вариант2.** В данном случае медленнее `СУММЕСЛИ`:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(--($C$2:$C$100=D2);$B$2:$B$100)
```

Здесь ограниченный диапазон указывать обязательно, иначе функция будеть лопатить весь столбец. И закрепить ссылки, чтобы диаазон не "поплыл" при копировании формулы по строкам.

**Вариант3.** Считаем по имени и товару.

*D2* = имя, *E2* = товар:

```
=СУММЕСЛИМН($B$2:$B$100;$C$2:$C$100;D2;$A$2:$A$100;E2)
```